# unable to update currentTime of html5 audio in chrome, Works in firefox and edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, laravel-5, html5-audio

audio files are unseekable in chrome, they don't work altogether in opera. However, I am able to see the audio file using firefox and Microsoft edge. I read on StackOverflow that I have to enable byte range support on the server. How I can do that and why it's working in firefox and edge if byte range is disabled. And I dont get any errors in console. Just that the file starts from the beginning whenever I update the `audioElement.currentTime`

Here is the code that I am using to seek the audio file

```
$(".progress2").on("click", function (event) {
    console.log("clicked")
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var left = (event.pageX - offset.left);
    var totalWidth = $("#custom-seekbar").width();
    var percentage = ( left / totalWidth );
    var vidTime = audioElement.duration * percentage;
    audioElement.currentTime = vidTime;
})
```

`<p id="custom-seekbar" class="progress2"><span></span></p>`

I am on a windows server, using xampp and Laravel. Spent a lot of time on this, let me know how I can get this working or if there are any alternatives to this.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting some time, I came to know that its the issue of server with byte ranges. I was running laravel server so used curl to verify if server handles byte ranges

```
curl -I http://i.imgur.com/z4d4kWk.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 146515
```

checked with laravel server, it was not working then checked with a laravel project running from xampp directly and it was working. Just leaving my answer here so if anyone else stumbles upon this in the future, it might save you some time.
My live server is also on xampp so I had no reason to fix the bytes ranges issue within laravel.